# jUnit with Spring MVC always returns 400 on POST

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, mockmvc

I am developing my first Spring Boot application with backend and frontend. Right now I am writing Unit tests for the Controller in the backend to test the Controller Response Codes.
My test class for the Controller looks like this:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = HorseEndpoint.class)
@ActiveProfiles({"test", "datagen"})
public class HorseEndpointTest {

    @MockBean   //the dependencies the controller class needs
    private HorseService horseService;
    @MockBean
    private HorseMapper horseMapper;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    Horse horseA = new Horse(-50L, "Pferd 1", null, new Date(0), Gender.MALE, null, null, null);

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Adding a valid horse should return the horse")
    public void addingHorse_valid_shouldReturnHorse() throws Exception {

        Mockito.when(horseService.addHorse(horseA)).thenReturn(horseA);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/horses")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(horseMapper.entityToDto(horseA)))
                .characterEncoding("utf-8"))
            .andExpect(status().is(201))
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.length()").value(1))
            .andDo(print());
    }
}
```

The code in the Controller class for POST looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/horses")
public class HorseEndpoint {

    @PostMapping(value = "")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public HorseDto addHorse(@RequestBody HorseDto horseDto) {
        Horse horse = horseMapper.dtoToEntity(horseDto);
        try {
            horse = horseService.addHorse(horse);
        } catch (ValidationException v) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "The horse data provided is invalid: " + v.getMessage(), v);
        }
        return horseMapper.entityToDto(horse);
    }
}
```

The problem is, as soon as I run the tests, the output file will show this error:

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.046 s <<< FAILURE! - in endpoint.HorseEndpointTest
addingHorse_valid_shouldReturnHorse  Time elapsed: 0.124 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Response status expected:<201> but was:<400>
```

Note that calling the POST Method from the frontend works without any problems. Exceptions of type `ValidationException` are only thrown in the Service Layer, but as I overwrote the function addHorse() with Mockito.when(), so the validation there does never take place, right?
So my guess is that it somehow fails to create a valid JSON from the Dto in the test class to pass to the controller. I already had a look on other related SO questions, but none of the solutions seemed to work.
Note: I already checked that the Date Types from Test class and Dto class are consistent.

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller don't know about the mocked `horseService` you create in your test. You have to inject into the controller in some way.

You can see some examples on how to do that on https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/guide-spring-boot-controller-tests/#mockitoextension-and-mockmvc

Comment: @BenjyTec: If my answer solved your problem, feel free to mark my answer as accepted. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Three years have passed, and I finally understood that Mockito only mocks the method call on the exact object that you provided to Mockito in `Mockito.when` . So I am marking this as accepted :)